# Connect to a Network over wifi or ethernet adapter, with twrp and use the terminal?

Tags: wi-fi, twrp, networking, nexus-5, terminal

Im a noobie with twrp and android, i have Install it on a very cheap Nexus 5 and it works.

Is it possible now, connect with twrp to a network with the terminal, if not possible over WiFi could it be work with an ethernet adapter?

Can i modify or upate twrp to get network functionality?

Comment: I want only twrp on the phone without any android or rom an execute some terminal network commands, is it not possible?

Comment: TWRP is only a lightweight OS that AFAIK does not contain drivers for Wifi or Ethernet. You may be able to modify TWRP but effectively that would be like building your own custom ROM which isn't easy and requires to learn a lot.

Comment: @Robert no, building my own is not my intention and also not my area. Is it something similar to twrp with network functions, what is easy to install, handle, use and manage custom rom's if needed?